# Flutter Apps APK : Page not displayed same as when debugging on emulator/android device after installed the APK in Android device

Tags: flutter, rest

In my flutter apps, there are few pages and functions including:

1. Page for Articles - this page will getting all data from the Article API (I'm not using https://newsapi.org/ or Mockup API). The data that are supposedly shown in this page are like Cover Image, Title, Description, Month, and when click on each article will go to the detail page that will also display the contents of the Article. Same as News Apps function. So after I installed the APK on Android device, this page not showing anything and not getting any data.
2. Form page - that will send data to API and then will store the data to SQL server via API. This page is working accordingly.

So my question is, after I build an APK for this app, I installed the APK on my Android device, but the page for Article are not displayed even after I refreshing the page. Why this happen and how to fix it? Only this page got issue, other page is working.

Maybe some of you facing like my situation can share your opinion to me so I can get the ideas on how to fix it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be more helpful if you provided the code.
However, make sure that you're using the same logic for all the pages (the ones that work and the one that doesn't), and make sure that you don't have any syntax errors or logical mistakes (perhaps some lists that you put it in the screen but you don't fill it...).
Consider that it may also be from the API itself for that specific page.